# Unable to configure WCF service for net.tcp in IIS hosting multiple sites

Tags: wcf, iis, nettcpbinding, net.tcp

Trying to set up second web site in IIS 7, most/all of the mirrored services function except ones configured for net.tcp.  Trying to  access the .svc url, I receive the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

IIS binding configuration:

[image: IIS Site Bindings]

Advanced Settings:

[image: Advanced Settings]

Trying to follow answers found on Stack Overflow, none seem to work.
Content of the service's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="ServiceName">
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
              name="basic" contract="ServiceName.IService" />
            <endpoint address="nettcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
              name="netTCP" contract="ServiceName.IService" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://staging.localhost/ServiceName" />
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8033/ServiceName" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

Is there a trick to the net.tcp bindings?  What is correct configuration needed in the web.config?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `net.tcp` to the application (go to Advanced Settings and look under the Behaviors section - there'll be one called  Enabled Protocols).

Comment: @Tim Thank you.  Yes, I've added that behavior.  I should have included a screenshot.

Comment: Your setup looks good, is the Net.TcpListener service running? Have you tried restarting IIS?

Comment: @PatFromCanada Thank you for the reply.  Yes, the Net.TcpListener is running and I've also restarted IIS (running iisreset at the command line).

Comment: I would try removing the net.pipe entry, and the space before the net.tcp I had problems before when I had the N uppercase, took a server reboot after i corrected it to straighten it out, crazy as that sounds

Comment: @PatFromCanada Thank you for the reply.  It did not work.  Going to infer it is not possible to host net tcp on multiple sites on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot is worth a 1,000 words sometimes.  In IIS manager, right-click on the application "ServiceName" and select Manage Application->Advanced Settings.  In the advanced settings dialog box, check to see if you've added net.tcp to the Enabled Protocols:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I've included a screenshot of the advanced settings.